# how to implement slider for div images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have client images in two `div`s, and I need to implement them as a slider when I click on next arrow other images need to be displayed.There  should be left and right arrows once we click on next button other images to be displayed. In the same way one we click on back arrow previous images need to be displayed.Can anyone help me this? As I can't figure out how to do this.

In desktop it should as normal slider with all the images but in mobile versions I should display only one image per slider

```
 <div class="clients">
          <h4 class="clientss">Clients</h4>
            <div id="clientimage">
                <img src="image/clients/1.png" class="imageclient1" />
                <img src="image/clients/2.png" class="imageclient2" />
                <img src="image/clients/3.png" class="imageclient3" />                                      
            </div>              
            <div id="clientimages">
                <img src="image/clients/7.png" class="imageclient7" />
                <img src="image/clients/8.png" class="imageclient8" />
                <img src="image/clients/9.png" class="imageclient9" />                                          
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: try this http://www.cssauthor.com/best-jquery-slider-plugins/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are lots of ways to implement sliders, so this question is probably a bit too broad unless you can [edit] your question to show some JavaScript that you've already been working on and need help with. Also, your requirement is unclear (at least to me). Do the two divs mean that you want two separate sliders on the page, or are you trying to do one slider that alternates between showing each div (showing three images at a time)?

Comment: these  6 images are showing one by one right now.if i add 6 more images again they should display on next slide.

Comment: Bootstrap´s Carousel implemented it. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp. Hoping it helps...

Comment: corrected grammar and edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

"Slick slider"

> http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

This document itself clearly mentioned, how to implement.

"Happy Coding"

Comment: Ya tried that but i am facing one problem in one page if there are 5 image and in other page if there are 2 images if i give sides to move as 5 in other page it is displaying previous 3 +2 images.But i dont want to rpeat the images in next pages.